# Calculate possible date combination without year

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am trying to calculate possible date combination without year,

Input :

```
date_first = 1/1/2016,
date second = 31/12/2016
```

Output : in output I need a list of all possible combination of day and month see this example.

```
01/01 to 12/31
01/01 to 12/30
01/01 to 12/29
01/01 to 12/28, etc.
...............
01/02 to 12/31
01/02 to 12/30
01/02 to 12/29
01/02 to 12/28, etc.
..............
12/31 to 12/31
```

I calculated year range using

```
rngs = date_range('1/1/2016', periods=365, freq='M')

date_range_list = [rng.date() for rng in rngs]
```

but for calculating possible date combination without year , I need to run  two loops that is taking to long time. so if any one know please help me to resolved this issue. Thanks in advance.

**Let me clear more about problem I am getting :**

I want a list of all possible combination of day and month, like, if Input date range is **1/1/2016 to 4/1/2016,** combination output will be :

```
[['1/1',4/1], ['1/1','3/1'],['1/1','2/1']['1/1','1/1'],['2/1','4/1'],['2/1','3/1'],['2/1','2/1‌​'],....]
```

Comment: Your question is unclear to me, please display what the desired output is and won't the year matter here? For instance leap years?

Comment: edited with input and output

Comment: you just need to do `date_range_list = date_range('1/1/2016', periods=365, freq='M').date.tolist()`

Comment: Please see my output what i want, I want a list of all possible combination of day and month, like, if date range is 1 jan to 4 jan, combination will be , [['1/1',4/1], ['1/1','3/1'],['1/1','2/1']['1/1','1/1'],['2/1','4/1'],['2/1','3/1'],['2/1','2/1'],....]

Comment: @Alenthomas why is it taking so long? It should only be 365^2 combinations i.e. 133225

Comment: @MuhammadTahir If I know then why i ask here.

Comment: @Alenthomas ok got your point after your recent edit

Comment: @MuhammadTahir do you have any idea about this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `itertools.combinations`:

```
from itertools import combinations
import pandas as pd
rngs = pd.date_range('1/1/2016', periods=365, freq='M')
date_range_list = [rng.date() for rng in rngs]
result = combinations(date_range_list, 2)
```